# Как с помощью скрипта добавить класс блоку отталкиваясь от значения в URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Здравствуйте!**

Подскажите как с помощью скрипта можно добавить класс блоку при условии что в адресной строке встречается значение `/EN/` т.е. если адресная строка выглядит например вот так: `http://..../en/.....` (вместо точек меняющиеся значения), то добавить класс нужному блоку.

Скрипт найденный в сети и приложенный к вопросу срабатывает, но только если после значения `/EN/` больше нечего нет и адресная строка выглядит вот так `http://..../en/` т.е. строго заканчивается со значением  `/EN/`

```js
setClsDependOnUrl();
function setClsDependOnUrl() {
  let url = location.href;
  if (location.pathname == '/en/') {
    document.querySelector('#block').classList.add('ep');
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="block">

</div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста решит данную задачу в виде рабочего скрипта.

**Благодарю за ответ!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.pathname` это путь к ресурсу, поэтому и срабатывает только если EN на конце. В данном случае я бы рекомендовал искать в строке урла подстроку /EN/ с помощью например .indexOf

```
if (url.indexOf('/en/') !== -1)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за рабочее решение!